# How to encrypt and decrypt with RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding mode in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I don't know about cryptography and here is my problem: *RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding*.
I want to encrypt the data with *RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding* in vb.net.
Below is my code:

```
Public Function RSAEncryption(ByVal textToEncrypt As String) As String
    Dim cipher As RSACryptoServiceProvider = New RSACryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim data As Byte()
    Dim cipherText As Byte()
    Dim EncryptedData As String

    cipher.FromXmlString(public_key)
    data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToEncrypt)
    cipherText = cipher.Encrypt(data, False)
    EncryptedData = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText)

    Return EncryptedData
End Function
```

As above code, I can do encryption with my public key.
I want to know is:
Does my code meets the requirement for *RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding* since I don't know about *RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding*?
Any help will make me happy... Thanks...

Comment: The ECB part wouldn't apply to RSA and yes [you are using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f17a0e2k(v=vs.110).aspx) PKCS#1 padding. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: What I want to do is I want to call bank API. According to their information, I need to use RSA encryption method as their specification RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding. So, what i want to know is does my code really meets their requirement RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding. What is ECB? What is PKCS1Padding? I don't know them how to write in vb.net. That's why I'm asking you as above question. Thanks...

Comment: Thanks @HenkHolterman. Now I know my code is using PKCS#1 padding according to your link. For ECB, what should I do? please kindly advice me.

Comment: I really don't know how to apply ECB to RSA, I would think that makes no sense.